# Java Paho MQTT detect reconnection

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I am using a the Paho MQTT library for android and my application is exchanging live editing data. I want to disable an edittext if the app disconnects from the broker and enable it when connection is reestablished.

First part is easy enough the `MqttCallback` has a `connectionLost` method, but not reconnect. Also when debugging the the `IMqttActionListener` on the connect method I noticed that the event is not fired upon a reconnect.

So my question is if there is any way at all to detect a reconnect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the extended version of the MQTTCallback class [MQTTCallbackExtended](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallbackExtended.html).

It has a method called when a connection is established.

> **void connectComplete(boolean reconnect,
>                        java.lang.String serverURI)**
>
> Called when the connection to the server is completed successfully.
>
> Parameters:
>       reconnect - If true, the connection was the result of automatic reconnect.
>       serverURI - The server URI that the connection was made to.

Comment: You Sir made my day!